# Dereferencing an array key in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider this Perl script:

```
use strict;

my %new;
my $test_ref = [24, 26, 55];
$new{$test_ref} = 10;

foreach my $key (keys %new){
    print $key->[0];
}
```

When I try to access this element, it gives an error like:

> Can't use string ("ARRAY(0x...)") as an ARRAY ref

Why?

Answer (score 3):

Because a hash key is always stringified, and a stringified value of an array REFERENCE (which `$test_ref` is) is exactly that: `"ARRAY(0x...)"`. This is different from Java maps which can store arbitrary object as a key.

Therfore, your hash would have 1 ket-value pair, with the key being a string "`"ARRAY(0x...)"`"

So, when you have your `for` loop, it loops over all the keys (all 1 of them), and then assigns the key value (a string `"ARRAY(0x...)"`) to `$key` variable.

You then try to array-dereference that string - which of course can't be done since **it is not an array reference** - it is merely a string containing the string representation of what array reference used to be.

If you want to have "24, 26, 55" as 3 hash keys, you can do this:

```
my %new = map { $_ => 10 } @$test_ref;
```

If you actually want to store a list in a hash key, it's doable but not always (in your case of a list of integers, you can, but it's slow, clumzy and I can't imagine when you'd ever wish to.

```
# Trivial example:
my $test_ref = [24, 26, 55];
$new{ join(",",@$test_ref) } = 10;
foreach my $key (keys %new){
    my @list = split(/,/,$key);
    print $list[0];
}
```

This approach has some performance penalties, and can be optimized a bit (e.g. by memoizing the split results). But again, for pretty much ANY reason you might want to do this, there probably are better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Hash keys are normally stringified, so they lose the ability to act as a reference.

The core module [Tie::RefHash](http://Tie::RefHash) provides this capability:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::RefHash;

tie my %new, 'Tie::RefHash';
my $test_ref = [24, 26, 55];
$new{$test_ref} = 10;

foreach my $key (keys %new){
    print $key->[0];
}
```

Good job using strict.  But warnings is even more important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (and I may be wrong) that you want to assign 24, 26 and 55 as the keys of `%new`.

If you want to do this, the following is what you're after:

```
use strict;

my %new;
my $test_ref = [24, 26, 55];

@new{@$test_ref} = (10) x @$test_ref;

print "$new{$_}\n" foreach keys %new;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the array reference `$test_ref`, then you want to use the array syntax (square brackets)

```
$test_ref->[0];
```

If you want to access the hash `%new`, then use the hash syntax (braces)

```
$new{$key}
```

What you are doing is using an array reference `$test_ref` as a key into a hash `%new` - what perl does is convert that array reference into a string to use at the key. It is the string and not the reference that is returned by `keys`.

You can't use references as keys and then get the reference back again (trivially).